# Sum rows in matrix whose first elements match?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have the matrix:

```
a=[1 2
   2 3
   1 5
   3 4
   2 9];
```

I would like to simplify it by summing together the second column of rows whose first column element matches. Therefore the above matrix `a` should become:

```
a=[1 7
   2 12
   3 4];
```

I'm at a loss as to how to do this functionally, in other words without a for loop. Thank you!

Comment: *[...] summing together the second column of rows whose first column element matches.* Please clarify/reformulate.

Comment: I mean I would like to sum together rows IF the elements in their first column match. For example, the rows `[1 2]` and `[1 3]` should be summed together (because both have 1 in the first column) but the rows `[1 2]` and `[2 4]` should *not* be summed together (because one has 1 in the first column and the other has 2...)

Comment: I'd say `1 5` in your example output is wrong output, isnt it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, made the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`accumarray`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [**`unique`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[u,~,subs] = unique(a(:,1))
out = [ u, accumarray(subs,a(:,2)) ]

out =

     1     7
     2    12
     3     4
```

For the one-line solution, you'd need an external function:

```
function subs = unique3rdOutput( vec )
   [~,~,subs] = unique(vec)
```

And then

```
out = [ unique(a(:,1)), accumarray(unique3rdOutput(a(:,1)),a(:,2)) ]
```

---

If you can ensure just positive integers in the first column, you can also use:

```
out = [ unique(a(:,1)) accumarray(a(:,1),a(:,2)) ]
```

or as suggested by Luis Mendo:

```
out = [ (1:max(a(:,1))).' accumarray(a(:,1),a(:,2)) ]
```

Comment: That's awesome, works very well with your final edit. I'm wondering, is it possible to make `unique` return `subs` directly such that I can write the whole thing on a single line? I'm asking out of curiosity only (I realize it would be less efficient this way as I'd have to call `unique` twice, once to generate `u` and once to generate `subs`) because maybe it'll be useful for me in some application down the line.

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy solution to get it into one line.

Comment: @space_voyager _If_ your first column always contains integers 1, 2, 3,... (in any order, but starting from `1` and without any gaps) you don't need `unique`, and so you can have a single line `out = [ (1:max(a(:,1))).' accumarray(a(:,1),a(:,2)) ]`

Comment: @LuisMendo My first answer was: `out = [ unique(a(:,1)) accumarray(a(:,1),a(:,2)) ]` - but I edited it out, as it works just for the case mentioned by you. It's not in the revision history, as the edit came to early.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these suggestions!